# What constitutes luxury goods?

Tags: tropico-4

I just received an objective stating to export 500 luxury goods.  However, it didn't say which of the many things I'm exporting are luxury goods (apparently none).

What constitutes luxury goods?

Comment: I suspect a luxury good is anything produced in a factory, like cigars, jewelry, furniture, canned coffee, etc.  Do you have any factories?

Comment: I've been exporting canned coffee and cigars for quite a while. The meter hasn't left 0 yet, although it might just not have updated yet. Meters this mission seem to lag a bit.

Comment: Check if you have to export to a certain country, the meter might not go up because the country giving the objective isn't importing canned coffee or cigars. You can check the almanac to see which country is importing each item and build a factory for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Luxury Goods is it's own resource. It is imported by default, but I'm not sure why since I think that it has to be sold at the mall which will then make your citizens happier. The only way to obtain Luxury Goods is to import it from China; it's impossible to produce or export, so I believe that the objective actually states to import it. (i.e. Build a mall.)

[image: screenshot of Trade page of Almanac with a freehand circle over luxury goods and a smaller freehand circle over the lack of a country to export it to]

Comment: Hmm, I *did* misread that.  I thought for *sure* that dialog said *export*...